# We're all [unique], but tags should not be ambigous

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The tag wiki for [unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unique) reads:

> Refers to an object that is distinctly different from any other object in a collection.

We have questions with this tag which are about:

- Unique elements in a collection:
  [how to find unique items in a total data set](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32065995)
  https://stackoverflow.com/q/31854560
  [Remove Duplicates From Comma Delimited String](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11417421)
  [Unique values in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1960473)
- Generating unique values:
  [Create a unique number with javascript time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8012002)
  [Generate a random unique ID using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23032354)
  [Using hashcode for a unique ID](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21368492)
  [Unique string to identify user file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31461345)
  [How do I generate a unique ID without using AUTOINCREMENT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2787921)
- The SQL constraint of the same name:
  [Unique column definition in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21993756)
  [SQL unique : manual check vs catch exception](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26441658)
  [Make a varchar(50) column unique](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8446063)
  [Unique row constraint in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9189705)
- And more:
  [How to count unique characters (only letters and numbers)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22638440)
  [Generate all unique combinations of Items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21425346)
  [XSD Unique Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22697704)

At the moment of posting, the tag has about 2.7k questions. It seems to be ambigous and I believe it's not really useful.

Does it deserve to be burninated?

Comment: "We're all [unique]" - I'm not!

Comment: There is a [tag:unique-constraint] tag for constraints in SQL