# Add possibility to edit tags directly in the "Tagged questions" page

Tags: feature-request, tags, burninate-system

Every now and then burninate requests are created. Some of them concern tags that are not very extensively used (e.g. [Exclude [exclude]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303434/exclude-exclude)), so we can clean them up manually. The feature of *inline tag editing* is very helpful in this case.

However, it would be even more convenient if the same feature was available directly in the "Tagged questions" page, to allow removing such tags without the need of opening the question:

[image]

This would allow really fast&convenient handling of the aforementioned burnination requests.

The described feature should be of course available only to 10k+ users, to match with the conditions for *inline tag editing* privilege.

Some more examples, just from the first results page for "burninate request" search on MSO, when simply quick deletion of an unwanted tag is sufficient and could be safely done:

- [Catcall due [calculated]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303510/catcall-due-calculated)
- [Is it time to [wrap] it up?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302836/is-it-time-to-wrap-it-up)
- [We're all [unique], but tags should not be ambigous](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302732/were-all-unique-but-tags-should-not-be-ambigous)
- [Stop protecting [protect]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302679/stop-protecting-protect)
- [Have this tag return to the [source]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302467/have-this-tag-return-to-the-source)
- [Let's burn the [source-code]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292086/lets-burn-the-source-code)

Comment: Do you really think it's a good idea to allow users that can't see the _whole_ question, to edit the tags?

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes, in case of such obvious tag burninations as the provided example.

Comment: Burninations which often call for tags to be replaced by something else.

Comment: @Cerbrus And often they are not, as in the provided example :)

Comment: 1 example where it's not a problem doesn't make it okay to implement it.

Comment: @Cerbrus Good point, I've added more examples.

Comment: @BartoszKP there is still the limiter for the number of edits you can do per x units of time.  I find having to open the post in another tab takes about as much time as the limiter places on us.

Comment: @NathanOliver Didn't experience/know that, that's also a good point.

Answer (score 3):

I really don't like this idea.  I think it directly contradicts the established guidelines for the burnination system and the editing system overall.

---

#### This is against the spirit of the editing system

According to the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing),

> Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than you found it

So a feature-request that allows for incomplete edits, even for 10k+ users seems like a bad idea.  It's hard to tell from the question preview which tags are really appropriate anyway.  This feature would allow for not only sub-par overall edits, but also sub-par tag edits.

As [Patrice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2417948/patrice) [comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303611/add-possibility-to-edit-tags-directly-in-the-tagged-questions-page#comment239023_303615), this feature request might also be optimizing the wrong thing.  Burnination-related tag edits probably are the exception instead of the norm.  Making a feature oriented towards the less common use case could backfire and make the normal case harder to do correctly.

---

#### This is against the spirit of the burnination system

From the [burnination faq](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250934/4320665)

> #### How are tags removed? Is there other cleanup work that should be done first?
>
> There isn't and shouldn't be a tool for this usable by the general public. This is a manual process which involves going to each individual question and editing it to remove the tag, along with fixing any other issues with each question.

Comment: The argument with "incomplete edits" is void. The feature of inline tag edits already encourages such edits. Also, see [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261069/2642204). In short: there is nothing wrong with minor edits, when they are made by 10k+ users (as they don't require review, so they won't clutter the review queue), as long as they improve the post.

Comment: @BartoszKP 2K users don't need reviews. In any case, I think this is too prone to mistakes. You use the burnination example, but I feel we have more tag edits that AREN'T burnination, and for those edits, you shouldn't be able to edit without reading the full post. Providing a tool for the "edge case" that can break the more common usecase seems bad to me

Comment: @BartoszKP Actually, it's not.  "Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than you found it" from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing).  This applies to all edits suggested or otherwise.  See also the latest meta discussion for [Making a good edit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303219/how-do-i-make-a-good-edit).

Comment: @Patrice If 2K users don't need reviews then if my math skills are still valid so do 10k+ :P and they are the target group for this feature. As for the rest of your comment, you have a point. Although it applies to any feature that allows changing something: yes, people do mistakes :)

Comment: @Patrice I like the points you elaborate on.  Mind if I edit them into my answer? Feel free to edit them in yourself if you want.

Comment: @ryanyuyu not at all, go ahead! thx for asking, but I'm happy to be paraphrased ^^

Comment: @BartoszKP yes, but the feature you ask for makes it easier to do mistakes on the thing that people do 80% of the time. I don't think a new feature to help the least common usecase while potentially increasing mistakes in the most common one is appropriate.

Comment: @ryanyuyu There are many places with different formulations of this "rule" (e.g. the discussion you provide speaks of edits "as complete as possible") and whole "minor edit" notion is disputed (e.g. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252249/what-is-wrong-with-minor-edits). Anyway, we are not employed here: when I have the time to do some simple clean-up and not spend hours correcting every spelling mistake in numerous posts, then why not let me do just that? Every improvement is valuable, especially fixing tags.

Comment: @BartoszKP the point still stands that making tag edits without reading the whole question is unreliable.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I like Patrice's argument, and some of yours, but I completely don't buy the "too minor edit" nonsense :)